# How to take inputs in multiple textviews?

Tags: java, android

i am new to development. i am creating an android calculator app with advanced functionality.The thing is i am using text view for taking and displaying inputs/outputs. My question is, how can i take Multiple inputs in multiple Textviews.

For example i have 3 text views,when user will enter 1st input in first textview(by default) and when user press the specific button it moves automatically to next textview . In some cases i want to take 2 inputs and in some cases i want to take 3 , 
How can i achieve this

Note: I dont want to use edit text , coz all buttons of already available in my app.Using Edit text will make softkeyboard to appear, and then for hiding the softkeyboard, i need to use hiding code lines in every class

Comment: `EditText` is the only tool for getting user input. I would suggest you read the basic android documentation first and then start building your calculator application.

Comment: You can hide the softkeyboard opening up in your `Activity` from configuring it in `AndroidManifest.xml`.

Comment: @ReazMurshed Could yo tell me how to move to cursor from one text view to another specific textview

Comment: Implement this with `EditText` instead of `TextView`. You will get the implementation automatically. Or you might consider using `TextInputLayout` as well.

Comment: Actually with Edit text user need to touch next edit text to enter a value , but i want to give them option for a button, just press the button and it will move byitself to next view

Comment: The Android Keyboard has a button to do exactly the same. Please check.

Comment: @AndroidDev If I understand correctly, your mode of input is through buttons right?

Comment: @Sagar and yes, moving to next input is also thru button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like following:

```
private TextView[] textViews;

private TextView tvCurrentEditing;
private Button btnNext;
private Button btnPrev;
private Button btnSetText;
private int index = 0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    textViews = new TextView[3];

    //Initialize all your textviews like textViews[0] = findViewById(<textview-id1>);
    //textViews[1] = findViewById(<textview-id2>);
    //textViews[2] = findViewById(<textview-id3>);

    tvCurrentEditing = textViews[index];// I am assuming this is your first 

    //initialzie btnSettext
    btnSettext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tvCurrentEditing.setText("<what ever you want");
        }
    });

    //initialize next buton
    btnNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(index < textViews.length) {
                index++;
            }
            tvCurrentEditing = textViews[index];
        }
    });

    //Initialize previous button
    btnPrev.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(index > 0) {
                index--;
            }
            tvCurrentEditing = textViews[index];
        }
    });

}
```

The names of the views could be different. The point is always use `tvCurrentEditing` whenever you want to change data of TextView. And update `tvCurrentEditing` whenever needed.

Comment: your code looks better , let me add this code in into my application

Comment: one more thing to clear, for every textview i need to write these two line of code to initialze
mainTextView2 = textViews[0];
mainTextView = findviewbyId(R.id.maintextview2);

Comment: Updated my answer